# Optimizing Assets in Symfony Framework

Tags: symfony, assetic, php-5.6

I would like to add assets to each bundle that uses it.

This is my current config.yml config:

```
assets:
    bootstrap_css:
        inputs:
            #Original File
            - %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/less/billing.bootstrap.less
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle/Braincrafted/Bundle/BootstrapBundle/Resources/less/form.less
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../src/HomeBundle/Resources/css/main.css
        filters:
            - lessphp
        output: css/bootstrap.css
    bootstrap_js:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/transition.js
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/alert.js
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/button.js
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/carousel.js
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/collapse.js
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/modal.js
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/popover.js
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/scrollspy.js
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/tab.js
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/affix.js
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../src/HomeBundle/Resources/js/bootbox.js
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle/Braincrafted/Bundle/BootstrapBundle/Resources/js/bc-bootstrap-collection.js
        output: js/bootstrap.js
    jquery:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/jquery/jquery.js
        output: js/jquery.js
    DataTables_css:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../src/HomeBundle/Resources/css/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.css
        filters:
            - cssrewrite
        output: css/dataTables.css
    DataTables_js:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../src/HomeBundle/Resources/js/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../src/HomeBundle/Resources/js/DataTables/bootstrap.js
        output: js/dataTables.js
    #Xeditable
    xeditable_js:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../src/HomeBundle/Resources/js/xeditable/bootstrap-editable.min.js
        output: js/xeditable.js
    xeditable_css:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../src/HomeBundle/Resources/css/xeditable/bootstrap-editable.css
        output: css/xeditable.css
        filters:
            - cssrewrite
    growl_js:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../src/HomeBundle/Resources/js/growl/jquery.bootstrap-growl.min.js
        output: js/growl.js
    sortable_js:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../src/HomeBundle/Resources/js/sortable/source/js/jquery-sortable-min.js
        output: js/sortable.js

#java: /usr/bin/java
filters:
    lessphp:
        file: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/HomeBundle/Assets/Filter/lessc.php
        apply_to: "\.less$"
        # Formatter options: compressed, lessjs, classic
        formatter: "compressed"
        preserve_comments: false
    cssrewrite: ~
    #closure:
    #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
    #yui_css:
    #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"
```

I am compiling the Bootstrap js and css file from source to reduce the number of requests.
Some of the Assets (Jquery Libraries) will be needed by some Bundles exclusivly.
But I don't want to tell an user add these files to your main config.
I don't feal that that is correct.
So I am looking for a way to add them to bundle config files.
But so far I could only find howtos and examples for router or service config.
But not for the data in the main config file.
I tried to add it as an extension but couldn't figure out how it works.

I tried this:

```
    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('config.yml');
```

and added the stuff for the current module into the assetic section.
But it didn't work.
So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assets in config are predefined assets available in your app, so now you just need to reference to them in your templates.

Comment: The Reference inside the templates are working. That is not my current Issue. I'm trying to deliver the bundles with own javascript libraries and less style definitions (if required) and to compile them in a smaller set of files (to reduce the number of requests). But I can't find a way to define asset sets per bundle.